# Normalizing Data in order to Select Distinct in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please bear with me, since I'm new to SQL Server. I'm working with a dataset that has about 2850 people in it, who appear multiple times, making it about 18,500 lines long, so while I could edit this all by hand it would take a while. I wanted to do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, RACE
INTO new_table
FROM table_name;
```

But it turns out that my race data isn't cleaned very well. As seen below, Person 27 has been listed as both white and Hispanic. Not everyone has this issue, but a good chunk of people do.

```
+----+----------+
| ID |   RACE   |  
+----+----------+
| 27 | Hispanic |  
| 27 | Hispanic |  
| 27 | White    |  
| 27 | White    | 
| 27 | White    |  
| 27 | White    |  
+----+----------+
```

I want to run through the data, take use the instance of race that is listed the most, and reassign it to them, so that I can then SELECT DISTINCT. So that it will go from the table above to:

```
+----+----------+
| ID |   RACE   |  
+----+----------+
| 27 | White    |  
| 27 | White    |  
| 27 | White    |  
| 27 | White    | 
| 27 | White    |  
| 27 | White    |  
+----+----------+
```

I realize that this might take multiple steps, but anyone have an idea of how I can do this, rather than cleaning by hand, or doing it in Stata or Excel? Thanks!

Comment: Can it be written as mutiple queries or you want on simple big query to do that job ?

Comment: I'd prefer one big one, but if multiple is the best way, then that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
SELECT ID, RACE
INTO new_table
FROM (SELECT id, race, count(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY id, race
     ) ir
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  In the event of ties, this will arbitrarily choose one race.

`ROW_NUBMER()` is a window/ranking function.  It assigns sequential numbers starting at one to each group defined by the `PARTITION BY` clause.  The ordering is specified by the `ORDER BY`.  So, the value "1" is assigned to the row with the largest `COUNT(*)` value for each `id` . . . and the outer `WHERE` chooses this row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was wondering if you could explain what seqnum and ir mean/do (you know, the whole teach a man to fish thing).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best or most efficient way, but I would use a combination of `row_number()` and a `common table expression`.

Using only the data you provided, this works for me:

```
create table #temp (
id int,
race varchar(10)
)


insert into #temp
select 27, 'Hispanic'
union all select 27, 'Hispanic'
union all select 27, 'White'
union all select 27, 'White'
union all select 27, 'White'
union all select 27, 'White'




with foo
as (
    select id, 
        race, 
        row_number() over (partition by id, race order by id, race) as cnt
    from #temp
)
update #temp
set race = (
    select top 1 race
    from foo
    where id = #temp.id
    order by cnt desc
)


select *
from #temp
```

I'd suggest creating a backup of your data first in case something goes awry.

I'd also supply a SQLFiddle link, but that site doesn't seem to be responding at this moment.